# Designing text in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, field-calculator, labeling, qt-designer

I want to write cubic meters in QGIS 3, I searched a lot but I didn't find any instructions.

Is there a way to write cubic meters as `m³`?

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @Mapperz](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340537/designing-text-in-qgis#comment555894_340537):

> On windows use cm\u00b3 m\u00b3 or km\u00b3 - In QGIS labelling you
>   need to convert the number field (like area) to a string like: 
>   to_string (round(Area, 2)) ++'m'+'³'